# How do I load a native library from Java depending on the use-case?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native, loadlibrary

I have a use-case depending on which I want to load libraries.

```
if(useCase) {
  Static { System.loadLibrary("a") };
}
else {
  Static { System.loadLibrary("b") }; 
}
```

Till now, I had just one library to load so I was loading it static in the class declaration but now I have this use-case and depending on it I need to load the library.

I was trying to load the library in the constructor only but any static declaration inside a constructor is not allowed, and I am confused what other ways are there by which I can achieve the same?

I want to load the libraries as static only. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to put static blocks inside an `if` statement, instead of having an `if` statement inside a static block?

Answer (score 0):

Please use custom class loader. below is the link for more info
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to call `loadLibrary()` from **static {}** (class) constructor, because this way you ensure that the code that implements native methods of your class, is available when the classloader needs it to initialize the class, like here:

```
public class ClassWithNativeMethods {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("a");
    }
    native void method1();
}

class ClassThatUsesClassWithNativeMethods {
    ClassWithNativeMethods field = new ClassWithNativeMethods();
}
```

If your Java has two different scenarios that involve loading different native libraries, you can load this library before loading this class:

```
public class ClassWithNativeMethods {
    native void method1();
}

class ClassThatUsesClassWithNativeMethods {
    ClassWithNativeMethods field;

    public ClassThatUsesClassWithNativeMethods(bool useCase) {
        if (useCase) {
            System.loadLibrary("a");
        }
        else {
            System.loadLibrary("b");
        }
        field = new ClassWithNativeMethods();
    }
}
```

If the *condition* is **static**, you can use it inside static constructor:

```
public class ClassWithNativeMethods {
    static {
        if (BuildConfig.useCase) {
            System.loadLibrary("a");
        else {
            System.loadLibrary("b");
        }
    }
    native void method1();
}
```

Comment: I am new to native library loading, can you tell me what is BuildConfig and what all do I need to change to make in the BuildConfig to load as static?

Comment: **BuildConfig** above is just an example. Android Studio by default prepares such class with `static final` data for you, but this could be any class that has static  `useCase` boolean field, it does not even need to be *final*.